# Silverstripe: querying many_many in ShortCodeHandler and use Image manipulation functions

Tags: php, silverstripe

In Silverstripe 3.0.5 I'm trying to query Images from a many_many Relation in a ShortCode function. I'm able to see (Debug) all the Data when I querying with SQLQuery() but do not know how I would use Image/GD functions like SetWidth or CroppedImage that I usually can use with Images in the Template when not querying per SQLQuery. I can directly refer to $Filename in Template. But is there a way to use the Image manipulation functions (SetWidth, CroppedImgae ...) in Template the way I'm querying the data or how should I get the GalleryImages in GalleryShortCodeHandler to be able to do so?

```
class Page extends SiteTree {
    $many_many = array(
        "GalleryImages"=>"GalleryImage"
    );
...
    public function GalleryShortCodeHandler($arguments,$caption = null,$parser = null) {
        $sqlQuery = new SQLQuery(); 
        $sqlQuery->from("GalleryImage"); 
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('Page_GalleryImages','"GalleryImage"."ID" = "Page_GalleryImages"."GalleryImageID"');
        $sqlQuery->addLeftJoin('File','"File"."ID" = "Page_GalleryImages"."GalleryImageID"');
        $sqlQuery->addWhere('"PageID" = ' . Controller::curr()->ID);
        $rawSQL = $sqlQuery->sql();
        $result = $sqlQuery->execute();

        $returnedRecords = new ArrayList();
        foreach($result as $row) { 
            $returnedRecords->push(new ArrayData($row)); 
        }
        $customise = array();
        $customise["Images"] = $returnedRecords;
        // Debug::show($customise);
        $template = new SSViewer("Gallery");
        return $template->process(new ArrayData($customise));
    }
...

class GalleryImage extends Image {
    static $db = array(
        "Descrition" => "Text"
    );
    static $belongs_many_many = array( 
        "Pages" => "Page" 
    );
...

Debug output looks like:
Debug (Page::GalleryShortCodeHandler() in Page.php:211)
Images =
    ArrayList
        ID = 65
        Descrition =
        PageID = 17
        GalleryImageID = 65
        SortOrder = 1
        ClassName = GalleryImage
        Created = 2013-04-24 14:20:28
        LastEdited = 2013-04-24 14:20:28
        Name = xyz.png
        Title = xyz
        Filename = assets/Gallery/xyz.png
        Content =
        ShowInSearch = 1
        ParentID = 1
        OwnerID = 2
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better of staying in the realm on the ORM so that the GalleryImage objects would be understood as Images object by the template parser, you would then be able to use the standard image manipulation functions. Maybe something along these lines:

```
public function GalleryShortCodeHandler($arguments,$caption = null,$parser = null) {
    $customise = array();
    $customise["Images"] = 
        GalleryImage::get()->
        leftJoin('Page_GalleryImages','"GalleryImage"."ID" = "Page_GalleryImages"."GalleryImageID"')->
        leftJoin('File','"File"."ID" = "Page_GalleryImages"."GalleryImageID"')->
        where('"PageID" = ' . Controller::curr()->ID);
    // Debug::show($customise);
    $template = new SSViewer("Gallery");
    return $template->process(new ArrayData($customise));
}
```

Comment: Thank you @jfbarrois! This is what I was after. The Join to File was not necessary anymore since on the ORM side Image gets the File-Details automatically.